# How do you animate the opening and closing of accordion sections in Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: accordion, zurb-foundation, animated

How do you animate the opening and closing of accordion sections in Zurb Foundation 4?

I've done extensive searching on Zurb Foundation's Google group and couldn't find any answers there either.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a fairly simple jQuery plugin to get this working. The plugin has default options, while also allowing overrides via the data-options attribute.

Tested on Foundation 5.

Here's the plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.accordionAnimated = function() {

        var
            $accordion = this,
            $items = $accordion.find('> dd'),
            $targets = $items.find('.content'),
            options = {
                active_class : 'active',    // class for items when active
                multi_expand: false,        // whether mutliple items can expand
                speed : 500,                // speed of animation
                toggleable: true            // setting to false only closes accordion panels when another is opened
            }
        ;

        $.extend(options, Foundation.utils.data_options($accordion));

        $items.each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('a:eq(0)').on('click.accordion', function() {
                if(!options.toggleable && $items.eq(0).hasClass(options.active_class)) {
                    return;
                }

                $targets.eq(i)
                    .stop(true, true)
                    .slideToggle(options.speed);

                if(!options.multi_expand) {
                    $targets.not(':eq('+i+')')
                        .stop(true, true)
                        .slideUp(options.speed);
                }
            });
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

and the plugin is simply invoked via

```
$('.accordion').accordionAnimated();
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using Foundation's HTML classes:

```
.top-bar-section {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
  -o-transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, I tried adding this to my style.css file but it didn't animate the opening or closing of the accordian sections?

This is the HTML class I'm using for the accordians:

     <div class="section-container accordion" data-section="accordion">

Comment: you could try using the `.section-container` class as your selector - hard to say without seeing your code or knowing what version of Foundation you're using. My answer is based on code from Foundation 4.3 docs.

Comment: I'm playing with the example for Foundation 5, the code is here:  http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html --- I tried applying your suggestion to the ".accordion .content.active" selector but it didn't work.  Thanks, Shawn!

Comment: That CSS snippet Shawn posted has nothing to do with the accordion component (it's related to topbar component), nor it's a mixin useful for Trinity's case. If OP is using SCSS, the correct mixin to use for adding a transition is '@include single-transition()'